# Mouse movement inside grid

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, point, swingutilities

I've created a grid, and a double array of my class `gridBalls`.

`gridBalls` has an `int` type, and you pass to it a number to determine 
what to draw in the grid, like 0 blank, 1 ball etc.

What would the code look like in my `mousedragged` if I wanted to lets say 
click on the slot [0][0] on my grid (pretend its a ball), drag my mouse 
to the right and draw a horizontal line (type 3 in this example), or if I 
dragged my mouse bottom and it drew a vertical line (type 2)

```
public class connectiontest extends JApplet implements Runnable, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    Thread t;

    int GRIDSIZE = 6;
    int gridLevel = 1;

    JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel (null);
    JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel (new GridLayout (GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE));
    gridBalls[] [] panelGrid = new gridBalls [GRIDSIZE] [GRIDSIZE];

    public void init ()
    {
        getContentPane ().setBackground (Color.black);
        getContentPane ().setLayout (null);
        setSize (600, 600);

        gamePanel.setBounds (80, 120, 450, 450);
        gamePanel.setEnabled (true);

        menuPanel.setBounds (10, 10, 580, 100);
        menuPanel.setBackground (Color.black);
        menuPanel.setOpaque (true);
        menuPanel.setBorder (BorderFactory.createLineBorder (Color.white, 1));

        getContentPane ().add (gamePanel);
        getContentPane ().add (menuPanel);

        t = new Thread (this);
        drawGrid ();
        levels ();
        t.start ();
    }


    public void run ()
    {
        while (t != null)
        {
            try
            {
                t.sleep (20);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    private void drawGrid ()
    {
        for (int row = 0 ; row < GRIDSIZE ; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0 ; col < GRIDSIZE ; col++)
            {
                panelGrid [row] [col] = new gridBalls ();
                panelGrid [row] [col].setOpaque (true);
                panelGrid [row] [col].setBackground (Color.black);
                panelGrid [row] [col].clr = Color.black;
                panelGrid [row] [col].setBorder (BorderFactory.createLineBorder (Color.blue, 1));
                gamePanel.add (panelGrid [row] [col]);
                panelGrid [row] [col].addMouseListener (this);
                panelGrid [row] [col].addMouseMotionListener (this);
            }
        }
    }


    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e)
    {

    }


    public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e)
    {

    }


    public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e)
    {

    }


    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e)
    {

    }


    public void mouseMoved (MouseEvent e)
    {

    }


    public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < GRIDSIZE ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < GRIDSIZE ; j++)
            {
                if (e.getSource () == panelGrid [i] [j])
                {
                    repaint ();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e)
    {

    }


    public void levels ()
    {
        if (gridLevel == 1)
        {
            panelGrid [0] [0].clr = Color.green;
            panelGrid [0] [0].type = 1;
            panelGrid [4] [0].clr = Color.green;
            panelGrid [4] [0].type = 1;
            panelGrid [0] [5].clr = Color.blue;
            panelGrid [0] [5].type = 1;
            panelGrid [5] [2].clr = Color.blue;
            panelGrid [5] [2].type = 1;
            panelGrid [0] [4].clr = Color.red;
            panelGrid [0] [4].type = 1;
            panelGrid [3] [2].clr = Color.red;
            panelGrid [3] [2].type = 1;
            panelGrid [5] [0].clr = Color.magenta;
            panelGrid [5] [0].type = 1;
            panelGrid [0] [1].clr = Color.magenta;
            panelGrid [0] [1].type = 1;
            panelGrid [1] [4].clr = Color.orange;
            panelGrid [1] [4].type = 1;
            panelGrid [4] [2].clr = Color.orange;
            panelGrid [4] [2].type = 1;
            panelGrid [0] [2].clr = Color.cyan;
            panelGrid [0] [2].type = 1;
            panelGrid [2] [2].clr = Color.cyan;
            panelGrid [2] [2].type = 1;
            repaint ();
        }
    }
}

class gridBalls extends JLabel
{
    Color clr;
    int type = 0;


    public gridBalls ()
    {

    }


    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent (g);

        g.setColor (clr);
        // blank
        if (type == 0)
        {

        }
        // ball
        if (type == 1)
        {
            g.fillOval ((getWidth () / 10), (getHeight () / 10), (getWidth () - 14), (getHeight () - 14));
        }
        // vertical line
        if (type == 2)
        {
            g.fillRect ((getWidth () / 3), 0, (getWidth () / 3), getHeight ());
        }
        // horizontal line
        if (type == 3)
        {
            g.fillRect (0, (getHeight () / 3), (getWidth ()), (getHeight () / 3));
        }
        // corner piece top>right
        if (type == 4)
        {
            g.fillRect ((getWidth () / 3), 0, (getWidth () / 3), (getHeight () / 2));
            g.fillRect ((getHeight () / 3), (getHeight () / 3), (getWidth ()), (getHeight () / 3));
        }
        // corner piece top>left
        if (type == 5)
        {
            g.fillRect ((getWidth () / 3), 0, (getWidth () / 3), (getHeight () / 2));
            g.fillRect (0, (getHeight () / 3), (getWidth () / 3 + getWidth () / 3), (getHeight () / 3));
        }
        // corner piece bottom>right
        if (type == 6)
        {
            g.fillRect ((getWidth () / 3), (getHeight () / 2), (getWidth () / 3), (getHeight () / 2));
            g.fillRect ((getHeight () / 3), (getHeight () / 3), (getWidth ()), (getHeight () / 3));
        }
        // corner piece bottom>left
        if (type == 7)
        {
            g.fillRect ((getWidth () / 3), (getHeight () / 2), (getWidth () / 3), (getHeight () / 2));
            g.fillRect (0, (getHeight () / 3), (getWidth () / 3 + getWidth () / 3), (getHeight () / 3));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This `getContentPane().setLayout(null);` and `t = new Thread(this);` scare the willies out of me...You may also want to familiarise your self with the [Java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) - You're not going to win any friends by ignoring them

Answer (score 1):

The overall construction of you layers makes it very difficult to actually get the paint effect to work properly.

However, your mouse handler events would look something like...

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    clickPoint = e.getPoint();
    clickPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(e.getComponent(), clickPoint, this);
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    dragPoint = e.getPoint();
    dragPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(e.getComponent(), dragPoint, this);
    repaint();
}
```

`clickPoint` and `dragPoint` are instances of `java.awt.Point`.

Your next problem is going to be getting this to paint...

You need to be able to paint over the content.  Because `paint` isn't double buffered, I'd personally avoid it, instead, I would override `paintChildren` (as `paintComponent` will be painted UNDER every thing else)...

```
@Override
protected void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
    super.paintChildren(g);
    if (clickPoint != null && dragPoint != null) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(clickPoint.x, clickPoint.y, dragPoint.x, dragPoint.y);
    }
}
```

**Suggestions**

- Avoid `null` layouts.  They are more trouble then they are worth, you'd be better of using a combination of layout managers, compound components and `EmptyBorder`s as required...
- Be careful with your `Thread`, Swing has some very particular needs when it comes to thread management...